# Image panning in sencha touch 2

Tags: image, scroll, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to have show a large image that the user can pan around (so scroll vertically & horizontally). But I can't get the image to scroll. This is what I have:

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.image.Floorplan', {

extend: 'Ext.Container',    
requires: 'Ext.Img',
xtype: 'floorplan',

config: {

    title: 'Floorplan',
    iconCls: 'locate',
    items: [
      {
        xtype: 'image',    
        scrollable: true,
        src: './resources/images/floorplan.png',
        height: 1570,
        width: 1047
      }
    ]
}
```

});

How can I make the image scrollable?

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{
    xtype:'panel',
    scrollable: true,
    items:[
        {
            xtype: 'image',
            src: 'http://www.hdwallpapersarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/0000037-2650.jpg',
            height: 1570,
            width: 2047
        }
    ]
}
```

There is no scrollable property for the image widget.